# Get vscode workspace git branch

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm building extension, how can I get active workspace git branch name programmatically?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `git` command line from your extension code.
I think the GitLens extension does that, maybe you can inspire from their code (see it on [GitHub](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/blob/master/src/git/git.ts#L127]))

Then, just run `git branch` to get the current git branch of your project.